# Build do Sublime Text 2 dá resultado diferente do iPython na linha de comando

Tags: python, sublime-text-2, python-2.7, scipy, ipython

Estou tentando migrar para o Sublime Text 2 e fazer tudo sem sair do programa. Antes eu rodava um script com a seguinte linha:

```
from scipy.stats import beta, bernoulli, gaussian_kde
```

No `shell` dentro do `iPithon` o comando roda normalmente.

Já se eu der o `build` (`cmd`+`b` ou Tools -> Build)  dentro do Sublime Text 2 ele não encontra o `scipy.stats` e retorna o seguinte erro:

> ImportError: No module named scipy.stats

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente o Sublime Text está usando outra instalação do Python (que não tem instalada a biblioteca Scipy).

Para usar a versão correta do Python, é necessário modificar uma configuração no arquivo `Python.sublime-build`, que fica em em `Preferences > Browse Packages » Python`. A configuração correta depende do seu sistema, suas configurações, e suas preferências pessoais:

## Opção 1: Alterar o caminho da instalação do Python

Defina o caminho da sua instalação do Python manualmente dentro da opção "cmd":

```
"cmd": ["C:/caminho/do/python/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
```

## Opção 2: Especificar o PATH

Copie o conteúdo da sua variável PATH para a opção "path":

```
"path": "C:\\caminho\\do\\python;C:\\caminho\\de\\outra\\coisa",
```

## Opção 3: Especificar o PYTHONPATH

Especifique o caminho do PYTHONPATH desejado em uma entrada do dicionário "env":

```
"env": {
    "PYTHONPATH":"C:/caminho/do/python;C:/caminho/do/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
},
```

Comment: Realmente, parece que o sublime já vem com um Python em vez de buscar a versão mais recente. Eu estou usando mac, então fiz uma modificação diferente da sugerida por você, mas valeu pela resposta! Primeiro peguei o `path` no shell com o comando `env`, depois colei o path no arquivo `python.sublime-build` com `"path": "caminho do env",`.

Comment: Ok! Vou dar uma organizada na resposta para contemplar todas as possíveis soluções. Também uso Mac, mas como somos minoria, deixei a resposta no padrão Windows, haha..