# Como configurar o SublimeREPL para o Anaconda (Python)?

Tags: python, sublime-text-2, ipython, anaconda, sublimerepl

Instalei o SublimeREPL para [executar a linha ou a seleção diretamente do Sublime Text 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8648/como-executar-a-linha-atual-no-sublime-text-2-ou-ide-que-permita-execucao-da-l/8651#8651). Entretanto, [da mesma forma que neste problema anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8571/build-do-sublime-text-2-da-resultado-diferente-do-ipython-na-linha-de-comando/8640?noredirect=1#8640), o SublimeREPL não está utilizando o Anaconda e sim outra versão do Python. Como configurar o SublimeREPL para achar o caminho do Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro da pasta `Packages/User` crie as pastas `SublimeREPL/config/Python/` e o arquivo `Main.sublime-menu` com o seguinte conteúdo (formato `json`), onde na linha `"cmd"` você irá trocar o `/path/to/Anaconda/python` pelo caminho correto para o `Anaconda` no seu computador. Isto vai criar mais duas opções no SublimeREPL, uma para o Python Anaconda e outra para o iPython Anaconda.

```
[
    {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "caption": "Python",
                    "id": "Python",

                    "children":[
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "Python - Anaconda",
                            "id": "repl_python",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "cmd": ["/path/to/Anaconda/python", "-i", "-u"],
                                "cwd": "$file_path",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "python",
                                "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "IPython - Anaconda",
                            "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "autocomplete_server": true,
                                "cmd": ["/path/to/Anaconda/python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                                "cwd": "$file_path",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "python",
                                "extend_env": {
                                    "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                                    "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
```

[Fonte: esta resposta do SOEN.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861176/how-do-i-setup-sublimerepl-with-anacondas-interpreter)